# Xamarin Android app error: package com.google.android.material.tabs.appcompat.app does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My app was working ok. Once day I plan to do some minor changes and everything goes haywire. After rebuilding it into a new project I keep getting this error. After searching I only get Android development errors, this one is related to Xamarin. Also tried reinstalling SDK again but no change. Any help fixing this is highly appreciated.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error: package com.google.android.material.tabs.appcompat.app does not exist

Comment: I think you are missing library

Comment: Please check the assemblies. And if you still can not fix this issue, please provide more details with code for us.